# US/Chinese newlyweds living in China, hoping to visit family in the USA, and return to our life in China

Tags: usa, visa, marriage, chinese-citizens

I'm an **American** expat, graduated university and came to **China** to teach in 2016. I met my **Chinese** wife in late 2020 and we got **married** here in February 2022. Our goal is to go to West Virginia to **visit** my family, see my hometown, and travel a little. We'd like to plan a two/three week trip. Then we want to **return** to China and continue working and living here. We are not wanting to immigrate to USA, merely want to visit and return.

Anyone had luck with getting a B2 tourist visa approved for their Chinese wife? Or could share their experience returning from abroad with their wife just to visit family?

Comment: This question is too broad for this site. Do you have a specific question you'd like to ask? If it remains at just "advice or suggestions" then this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates. Unfortunately unless you edit your question to focus it on a *specific problem(s)* you need help with, it is likely to be closed  https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask This might be helpful https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Comment: This is going to be hard--the US is going to suspect that you're trying to circumvent the usual delays in applying for a spouse.

Comment: @Traveller While there is a lot of extraneous stuff in the question the fundamental issue is a tourist visa for a spouse--a specific problem.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Indeed, however the OP does not explain what the *specific* problem of applying for a tourist visa for a spouse is *in their case*. Is it lack of ties (maybe not, since ‘working in China’ is mentioned) or of travel history? Adverse US immigration history?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Even if we knew the complete details of the OP’s current situation, and the complete details of a future US visa application — which we don't — the answer would still be an opinion.

Comment: @Traveller The general case of the spouse of a US citizen seeking a tourist visa is quite problematic--immigration is going to presume they're trying to avoid the wait of applying for permanent residence abroad.  I understand why the question was asked but I don't know any solutions.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I too understand why the question was asked, however AFAIK there *is* no solution other than to apply with an ironclad case and hope for a positive outcome. Based on the information the OP provided we cannot know if there are any weaknesses in their specific case (over and above the concerns typical in such instances) so I see little scope for anyone to even attempt to help. Other than generic advice to consult an immigration lawyer.

Comment: @Traveller I do agree there isn't likely to be an answer that the poster will like but I don't think that makes it a bad question.  It's one of these questions for which the answer probably is "you can't do what you want to".